# Browser Link Dashboard on Visual Studio 2013 RC

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I installed Visual Studio 2013 RC on Windows 7. I want to work with Browser Link Dashboard. But It isn't working. It shows that `No Browsers Connected` in the Refresh link. What should I do? Please Help

Comment: When i open Browser Link Dashboard, In the Connections tab No Connection available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be debugging a project that includes the right HttpModule for Browser link to work. 
It is mentioned in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/08/01/10430221.aspx) post.
An MVC project and Web forms will include the HttpModule that inserts the required JavaScript code into your pages for Browser link to work.
You can check that the bottom of your page have the following (view source):

```
<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/__vwd/js/artery"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->
```

An empty ASP.NET project does not work out of the box. 
Copying the following from an MVC project into the web.config of an empty ASP.NET project will insert the magic JavaScript, but it will also stop your page from displaying. Not sure how to just get the HttpModule that is needed and not the MVC view blocking. Visual studio will report that the browser is connected though.

```
<system.webServer>
   <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
   </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Would you know the answer for this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981468/visual-studio-2013-browser-link-is-not-showing-other-options-but-refresh

Answer (score 1):

to me what worked

```
<system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="Browser Link for HTML" path="*.html" verb="*"
             type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             resourceType="File" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```